# MODx-based website: Getting 500 Server Error

Tags: php, modx

I'm not a MODx developer, but trying to work on a website that is based on MODx.

I just tried adding a resource under another resource that also involved uploading a file. Then I went ahead and deleted the resource. Now, when I refresh the [page](http://oilfield.omron.com/about/careers/job-listings), all I get is just a 500 Server error.

Any idea what might be causing this? I've already deleted the cache as well.

Here are the errors I get in the error log (they are all notices):

```
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant E_DEPRECATED - assumed 'E_DEPRECATED' in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 2853
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant E_USER_DEPRECATED - assumed 'E_USER_DEPRECATED' in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 2854
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  type in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 3026
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  type in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 3026
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  type in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 3026
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  type in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 3026
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  type in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 3026
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  type in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 3026
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant E_DEPRECATED - assumed 'E_DEPRECATED' in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 2982
[11-Sep-2013 15:52:35] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant E_USER_DEPRECATED - assumed 'E_USER_DEPRECATED' in /home1/hidden/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 2983
```

Comment: Any error in apache errors log?

Comment: Just added the error log for today in my question.